# does a convex function have to have a maximizer?

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, set-theory

I've been trying to determine if the following statement is true or false:

Let X be a nonempty, convex and compact subset of the reals, and f: X $\to \Re$ a convex function. Then f has a maximizer.

I've been given hints that the statement is true, however I can't find a good proof, additionally the fact that it is false for a concave function is throwing me off.

My initial proof is as follows:

Let X=[A,B], then we have that f on (A,B) is continuous, from weierstrass's extreme value theorem we have that f takes on a maximum in the interval, call this point C. Then we can take the maximum of {f(A),f(B),f(C)}, and we have found the maximizer of f.

Comment: What do you mean by a maximizer?

Comment: @RichoddAsscraft I think it refers to the maximum value of the function.

Comment: Yes, this is from econ so I think the terminology is different from normal. A maximizer is just the maximum of a function (from what I understand).

Comment: Your proof is wrong because $X$ might not be an interval. For an interval, your proof is correct.

Comment: doesn't X have to be an interval because it is convex and compact?

Comment: I don't understand why is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem not enough. $X$ will be an interval $[A,B]$ in order to be convex and compact. The only assumption it seems you are missing is that $f$ is continuous. If you don't have continuity then your proof is wrong since you can't actually use Weierstrass.